# SQL Server - Table name as variable in query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, variables, sql-server-2012

First, I know this has been addressed before - I've done my research and as you'll see below, I have tried multiple versions to get this to work.

I am trying to set up a query in which a variable can be set and the query uses that variable. Here's my code:

```
-- Set to the category you want to check
DECLARE @validationCategory varchar = 'Dept'

DECLARE @validationTable varchar = (SELECT ValidationTable FROM MasterFiles..Categories WHERE Category = @validationCategory AND TableToValidate = 'xref')
DECLARE @validationField varchar = (SELECT ValidationField FROM MasterFiles..Categories WHERE Category = @validationCategory AND TableToValidate = 'xref')

EXEC('
SELECT DISTINCT Category
FROM MasterFiles.dbo.xref
WHERE Category = ''' + @validationCategory + '''
    AND (new_value NOT IN (SELECT ''' + @validationField + '''
                            FROM ' + @validationTable + ')
    AND old_value NOT LIKE ''%New%''
    OR (new_value IS NULL OR new_value = ''''))
    )'
)
```

When I run it I am getting this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

The most I've been able to glean from the error is that Level 15 means the error is correctable by the user. Great! Now if I could just find out exactly what the syntax problem is...

I'm suspecting it may be due to the fact that `@validationTable` is a *table*, not a string, but I'm not sure how to address that.

After some more research I then tried to put the query in a variable and then run EXEC on the variable:

```
--...
DECLARE @Query nvarchar
SET @Query = '
SELECT DISTINCT Category
FROM MasterFiles.dbo.xref
WHERE Category = ''' + @validationCategory + '''
    AND (new_value NOT IN (SELECT ''' + @validationField + '''
                            FROM ' + @validationTable + ')
    AND old_value NOT LIKE ''%New%''
    OR (new_value IS NULL OR new_value = ''''))
    )'
EXEC(@query)
```

That ran without errors, but I didn't get any output - just that it ran successfully.

After some more research about getting the output of a query as an EXECuted variable, I came up with this (from an example I found here on SO):

```
--...
DECLARE @vQuery nvarchar
SET @vQuery = '
SELECT DISTINCT Category
FROM MasterFiles.dbo.xref
WHERE Category = ''' + @validationCategory + '''
    AND (new_value NOT IN (SELECT ''' + @validationField + '''
                            FROM ' + @validationTable + ')
    AND old_value NOT LIKE ''%New%''
    OR (new_value IS NULL OR new_value = ''''))
    )'

DECLARE @vi int
--DECLARE @vQuery varchar(1000)

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL
    @query = @vQuery
    , @params = '@vi int output'
    , @vi = @vi output

SELECT @vi
```

That resulted in this error:

> Msg 214, Level 16, State 3, Procedure sp_executesql, Line 1
>   Procedure expects parameter '@parameters' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'.

So what's the correct way to go about this. In my research on this I've seen examples that use a stored procedure. I'd like to be able to do this without a stored procedure because this query will be used by copy/pasting the query into a query window in a client's SSMS, setting the table variable and running the query. Then moving on to the next client to do the same thing.

I need to be able to run this on servers installed with either SQL Server 2008 or 2012.

Comment: best way to figure out why your first attempt is wrong is to use `PRINT` to see what sql you're generating.. you have a `)` in the wrong place somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what your first attempt is generating..

```
SELECT DISTINCT Category
FROM    MasterFiles.dbo.xref
WHERE   Category = 'D'
        AND (new_value NOT IN (SELECT 'M' FROM M)
            AND old_value NOT LIKE '%New%'
            OR (new_value IS NULL OR new_value = '')
        )
    ) -- extra
```

This has an extra `)` and doesn't really make sense

On top of all of this.. you're declaring your variables as VARCHAR with no length which equals to 1 character

```
DECLARE @validationCategory varchar = 'Dept'

DECLARE @validationTable varchar = (SELECT ValidationTable FROM MasterFiles..Categories WHERE Category = @validationCategory AND TableToValidate = 'xref')
DECLARE @validationField varchar = (SELECT ValidationField FROM MasterFiles..Categories WHERE Category = @validationCategory AND TableToValidate = 'xref')
```

`@validationCategory` would equal to 'D' in this case.. Make sure you add appropriate lengths to your varchars

Answer (score 0):

First test, print the query variable ( @vQuery ), copy and paste it in a new query window and execute it. You're gonna identify where the error is exactly.

I think you need to do this, just like you do with your @validationTable:

```
DECLARE @vQuery nvarchar
SET @vQuery = '
SELECT DISTINCT Category
FROM MasterFiles.dbo.xref
WHERE Category = ''' + @validationCategory + '''
    AND (new_value NOT IN (SELECT ' + @validationField + '
                            FROM ' + @validationTable + ')
    AND old_value NOT LIKE ''%New%''
    OR (new_value IS NULL OR new_value = ''''))
    )'
```

Answer (score 0):

If @validationTable is a table variable and not a string then you need to interact with it differently.

Instead of

```
(
    SELECT ''' + @validationField + '''
    FROM ' + @validationTable + '
)
```

Try

```
(
    SELECT ''' + QUOTENAME(@validationField) + '''
    FROM @validationTable
)
```

SQL Server will now recognise @validationTable as an object.  I suspect, reading the error message, that your query has other issues.  Try outputting all dynamic SQL statements and testing them directly when debugging.

I've added the [QUOTENAME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx) function, as this will help protect you against [SQL Injection Attacks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).  It's a big topic but very much worth reading up on.